# Looping an Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

i am having trouble on how i should loop an image of mine like 50 times, but appear on different times.

This is my Code:

```
//Uploading car
var car1 = new Image();
car1.src = "http://images.clipartpanda.com/car-top-view-clipart-red-racing-car-top-view-fe3a.png";

//Setting properties of car
var x1 = 450;
var y1 = 50;
var speed1 = 10;
var angle1 = -990;
var mod1 = 0.2;

//Interval for animation
 var moveInterval = setInterval(function () {
     drawCar();
 }, 30);

//Drawing the car turning and changing speed
function drawCar() {
    x1 += (speed1 * mod1) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * angle1);
    y1 += (speed1 * mod1) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle1);

    context.save();
    context.translate(x1, y1);
    context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle1);
    context.drawImage(car1, -(car1.width / 2), -(car1.height / 2));
    context.restore();
     draw_multiple();


}

function draw_multiple() {
      var i;
      var obstacles = []; // How to put array so this code will work with array?
      for(i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
      drawCar ((i*70)+100,100, 30);
      }
 }
```

In this code is where i have drawn my image but the last function is the for loop function. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Something like this**

```
function draw_multiple() 
{
    var obstacles = {
        "item1": (5x3) + 2, // obstacles[0] returns 17
        "item2": (2/2) * 5, // obstacles[1] returns 5
        "anotherItem": "This is a string" // obstacles[2] returns "This is a string"
    };

    for(var i=0; i<10 ; i++) {
        drawCar ((i*70)+100,100, 30);
    }

    for(var i=0; i<obstacles.length ; i++) {
        drawObstacles( obstacles[i] );
    }
}
```

You need to create the function `drawObstacles()`.

Comment: Hey Rafael, thanks for that code but it is not working, is there a specific point where i should put the Code?

Comment: @TheGoodGuy You need to create the function called `drawObstacles()`.

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you again but i dont know how to make array values, im a beginner at programing in highschool

Comment: @TheGoodGuy hey man glad to see another future programmer.  Keep it up!  I added more code in the example above so you can see how easy it is to assign values to an array.  An array is nothing more than an object with multiple variables.  Check out this tutorial if you need help understanding arrays [JavaScript Array Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp).

Comment: Hey Rafael, so sorry to bother you but unfortunately it is not working. I put all the code on Jsbin for you to see: http://jsbin.com/xepefisovu/1/edit

Comment: I don't really know how to explain it man.  Just keep working at it.  You'll beat your head up over it but that's what programming is about.  Once you do this for a couple years everything with programming sort of clicks in your mind.  And im not saying that you can't learn it now.  I am saying that don't expect to just get it.  As a fellow programmer I recommend that you sign up with [CodeSchool](https://www.codeschool.com/) or [Team TreeHouse](http://teamtreehouse.com/).  If you can't pay for this kind of thing create a [goFundMe](http://www.gofundme.com/) account and you will get the money.

Comment: Go to your local public library and get books on JavaScript or any other programming language you want.  This is a good way to set your future with no investment except your time.